# javascript or jquery n number of contnet slider in asp.net mvc3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, slider

I have asp.net mvc3 application. wherein index page i am having say 100 of dynamic users comes from the database. I am trying to manage the view of first 12 users [1-12] in tiles on index page. but i need Next-Previous buttons aroud to main div control. if i clicks next , next 12 records [13-24] should be in view..so on. same in reverse for previous.

Can i perform with default jquery files given by template in  VS2010 mvc 3 ? what code i need to do ? which functions i need to use. or pease suggest any open source plugin...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a default ajax support.

I would do the following:

1. Create a partial view that contains a list of 12 users and a paging control. Paging control would have its own partial view.
2. Paging control would have Ajax action links with option to replace content of your user div.
3. My controller would return a partial view with a list of users for the selected page.

Comment: Ok..but isn't it posiible to fetch all records once and split into severals at client side... and represent? i need code infact

Comment: probably you are right... but somehow i need to buffer collection of users at page level, in the performance perspective. how to buffer the collection at client side in asp.net mvc 3